# Custom activities - different wait times depending on contact email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are trying to introduce some automated ways to test journeys, issue we have is that we cannot in any way speed up send for let's say contact with email thisistest@gmail.com in journey workflow. We can, of course, do a decision split but that complicates journey and basically doubles the setup.

My question is - can I build with custom activities one activity that will wait a different amount of time depending on customer/journey data? If yes I'd appreciate a guidance on what activity type to use - standard SFMC WAIT or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A custom activity would not be able to do this as it executes and hands off to the next activity in the flow.